# php while loop to select categories

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, categories

I have 1 table on the database :( SQL )

```
-- id
-- city_name
-- image
```

and I want to view every images inside them city, for example : USA has 3 images and Canada has 2, it will be looks like :

```
USA
image 01
image 02
image 03

CANADA
image 01
image 02
```

I tried this code, it will be view all the records mixed

```
$results1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($results1)) {

    echo $r[city_name]."<hr>";

    $city = $r[city_name];
    $results2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE city_name='$city'");


    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($results2)){
        echo '<img border="0" src="'.$r['image'].'">';
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: i did it, this code just for example, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correction in your code:**

You are overwriting `result set $r of first query into second while loop

```
    $last='';
    $results1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery order by city_name ASC");
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($results1)){

    if($last!=$r['city_name']) {    
    echo $r['city_name']."<hr>";
       $last = $r['city_name']; 
    }

    $city = $r['city_name'];

    $results2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE city_name='$city'");


        while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($results2)){ //change this variable

                    echo $r1['image'];

        }
   }
```

**Second solution:**

```
$data = array();
$results1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($results1)){
    $data[$r['city_name']][]=$r;
}
foreach($data as $key=>$images){
     echo $key.PHP_EOL; //city name
     foreach($images as $image){
         echo $image['id'].PHP_EOL; // each image id
         echo $image['image'].PHP_EOL; // each image for city
     }
}
```

Comment: This code will duplicate image for name, because in USA there is 3 images and Canada 2 images. i want echo USA and inside it 3 images after that echo Canada inside it 2 images, Thanks

Comment: Please see my second solution

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code with one query.

```
<?php
$cityImages = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
 $cityImages[$row['city_name']][] = $row['image'];
};
?>
```

Then you can use $cityImages array.